# Cakephp and custom authentification for mobile application

Tags: android, api, cakephp, authentication

Hey i'm working on a web application in combination with an android app. Now i want in my mobile app that the user have to log in with the same user data like on the web application. So i want to send a username and a password to the controller and in the login action of this controller the user should be verified and the additional user id should be send back to the application (the id is used for several operations in the app). I looked for the Auth Component of CakePHP but i don't find any solution for my problem. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());
    if($this->name == 'Specific') {
            // for the specific controller
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
    } else {
            // everything else
    }
}
```

checkout KVZ's rest plugin it may be of interest https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551873

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you need to do on the cakephp side of things, but if you want to have a set of account credentials stored securely and persistently on an Android device, I suggest you take a look at the [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthComponent has a `login()` method you can use to manually login users. Depending on the Cake version you're using this method also checks the credentials you supply (actually Auth is completely restructured in 2.0 in a way that's much more useful for situations like yours, it's worth taking a look!).

You can send in the login credentials from your android app any way you please (XML, POST parameters), extract them in your login action and send them to the AuthComponent (or, in 2.0, write a custom authenticator object to handle it all).