# Connecting Android Application With CakePhp website

Tags: android, http, cakephp, authentication

Is it possible to communicate an android Application with cakePhp website and share data? If it is possible, I want to create an application that can login into the website; my doubt is:

1. How to pass user name and password from our application to cakephp websites login page? Can anybody show me an example program?
2. How cakephp controller handle this request and respond to this request? Please show me an example program?

(I am a beginner in android and cakephp.)

Comment: Maybe this could help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551873/cakephp-2-0-and-mobile-application-authentication][1]

if not, let me know
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551873/cakephp-2-0-and-mobile-application-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Admad JWT Auth Plugin

If you use cakephp3 change your login function with this one :

```
public function token() {

        $user = $this->Auth->identify();


        if (!$user) {

            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username (email) or password');
        }

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                ],
                Security::salt())
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);
}
```

You can read this tutorial about REST Api and JWT Auth Implementation

http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/

Answer (score 7):

Quick answer -- YES!

We just finished pushing an Android app to the market place that does this exact thing. Here's how we did it:

1) Download and learn to use Cordova PhoneGap (2.2.0 is the latest version) within Eclipse. This makes the whole thing so much easier with just some HTML and a lot of Javascript.

2) In your JS, create methods that push the login information using AJAX parameters. Example:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

    $("#login").click(function() {
        $email = $("#UserEmail").val();
        $pass = $("#UserPassword").val();
            $.ajax({
                    url : yourURL + 'api/users/login',
                    async : false,
                    data : {
                        'email' : $email,
                        'password' : $pass
                    },
                    dataType : 'json',
                    type : 'post',
                    success : function(result) {
                            /**
                             * do your login redirects or 
                             * use localStorage to store your data 
                             * on the phone. Keep in mind the limitations of 
                             * per domain localStorage of 5MB
                             */
                            // you are officially "logged in"
                            window.location.href = "yourUrl.html";
                            return;
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, status, err) {
                        // do your stuff when the login fails
                    }
            });
    }
}
```

3) In Cake / PHP, your Users controller here will take the username and password data in the AJAX call and use that for its authentication.

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'Users';

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('api_login');
    }

    public function api_login() {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        if ($this->request->data && isset($this->request->data['email']) && isset($this->request->data['password'])) {

            $arrUser  = $this->User->find('all',array(
                    'conditions'=>array(
                            'email'=> $this->request->data['email'],
                            'password' => $this->Auth->password($this->request->data['password']),
                    )
                )
            );

            if (count($arrUser) > 0) {
                $this->Session->write('Auth.User',$arrUser[0]['User']);

                // Do your login functions

                $arrReturn['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $arrReturn['data'] = array( 'loginSuccess' => 1,'user_id' => $arrUser[0]['User']['id'] );

            } else {
                $arrReturn['status'] = 'NOTLOGGEDIN';
                $arrReturn['data'] = array( 'loginSuccess' => 0 );
            }
        } else {
            $arrReturn['status'] = 'NOTLOGGEDIN';
            $arrReturn['data'] = array( 'loginSuccess' => 0 );
        }
        echo json_encode($arrReturn);
    }
}
?>
```

That's pretty much it. You are now authenticated to CakePHP.

You do not need to use "api_", you can use any function name you want, but this helped us keep a handle on what we allowed mobile users to do versus web users.

Now, these are just the building blocks. You basically have to create a whole version of your site on the phone using HTML and Javascript, so depending on your application it may be easier just to create a responsive design to your site and allow mobile browsing.

HTH!

Comment: Can you give me the android code for passing username and password to the cakephp ? and also code for retrieving some data from the cakephp controller to the android application

Comment: can you please send me the android code for connecting cakephp website

Comment: The Android code is the Javascript listed above. You need to create an HTML file with two inputs, one with id UserEmail and one with id UserPassword. While I'm happy to help you out, I'm not going to write your code for you. The code to pass data back and forth from Cake is within the AJAX responses.

Comment: Hi, mr.JR how to use REST service to send data to my android application using JSON ???

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot send from your Cake website to the phone (Android or iPhone) without a push service of some kind. If you want to push data to your phone, the Android app must request it. JSON is client-end, so if you want to use REST, you have to use new HTML files to accomplish what you are trying to do and have the JSON do redirects.

Comment: I tried this same method to get data from the database and send it to my cordova app. But with the response json, there are some HTML attached at the bottom.. Is that normal?

Comment: @Kasun - not normally. Either your layout is being rendered (you missed the $ this-> autoRender = false ) or you need to set the layout appropriately with $this-> layout = 'ajax';

Answer (score -1):

if rebuild most of the view pages in cakephp into ajax will seem defeat the purposes of using cakephp as it is.

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question.